# How to make a file with python using nikkiepy

Tags: python

I've been stuck on C++ for a bit, so I decided to continue my python classes (In which I'm currently working with the Nikkiepy library) and I'm trying to figure out how to make a file. This is my current code:

```
import nikkiepy.files as npyf

npyf.mkfile("coakey", "./data", ".cde")
```

for some reason it keeps asking for a folder

Comment: Why are you using this library to create a file instead of using python's `with open`?

Comment: Because this library got recommended to me by some other developer, and it looks easier than other statements

Comment: Why was it recommended? What use case does it solve for you that python's built-in capabilities don't easily provide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using "Coakey" as the folder, you should instead do

```
import nikkiepy.files as npyf

npyf.mkfile(path="./", name="coakey", extension="cde")
```

Also, leave the "." out of the extension, because that gets added automatically